# Magento 1 - How to display static block based on dropdown selection of created attribute?

Tags: php, dropdown-attribute, product-page, magento-1.9.2.0

I am trying to display a static block based on the selection that has been made when adding a product in the magento backend.

So the situation is, I am adding the product and select a option from a dropdown attribute which has been created. The options are:

-Do not show table
-Show table 1
-Show table 2
and so on...

Static blocks have been created realated to the dropdown options:

-Static block table 1
-Static block table 2
and so on...

I am using the following code in the phtml file which I want to display it:

```
<?php if
($_product->getAttributeText('tableselect') == "Table 1"): ?>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('table_1_block')->toHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Its not working for me, what am i doing wrong here? Please help

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It may be that your product model does not contain the value. Try :

```
$choice = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('tableselect')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product));

if ($choice == "Table 1") : ..
```

It is worth debugging to check your values e.g

```
<?php var_dump($_product->getData('tableselect')) ?>
<?php var_dump($choice) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have managed to get this to work and as suggested I had to include the value in the model.

Comment: Should this code also work on Magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work. As stated by Fisheye Chris I had to make sure it was in the product model and used in the frontend. This is my working code now:

```
<?php
if ($this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('tableselect') == "Table 1") {
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('table_1_block')->toHtml();
}
```